# Get full class name with VBA / Selenium

Tags: vba, selenium, class

I am using VBA and selenium to automate Chrome.
The html code looks like this:

```
<div class="field Name">...</div>
<div class="field Note">...</div>
<div class="field label">...</div>
```

`webBrowser.FindElementByClass("field Name")` doesn't work.

If have to use a loop like this:

```
    lngCount = webBrowser.FindElementsByClass("field")

    For i = 1 To lngCount

       If webBrowser.FindElemetsByClass("field").Item(lngCount).??? = "field Name" Then

       End if

    Next i
```

I don't know the part where the ??? is.
How can I compare the complete class name with the string "field Name"?

Comment: Did you try webBrowser.FindElementByClass("field.Name")  ?

Comment: Also, did you try switching to using By method?

Comment: And what does doesn't work mean? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
With XPath you can check the full string including spaces:

```
webBrowser.FindElementByXPath("div[@class='field Name']")
```

And so you can do something if it exists:

```
If Not webBrowser.FindElementByXPath("div[@class='field Name']") Is Nothing Then
   'element exists, do something
Else
   'element doesn't exists
End if
```

Comment: You can also check it with findElementByCssSelector("div.field.Name") .

Answer (score 0):

.Attribute("class") should work:

```
lngCount = webBrowser.FindElementsByClass("field")

For i = 1 To lngCount

   If webBrowser.FindElemetsByClass("field").Item(lngCount).Attribute("class") = "field Name" Then

   End if

Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

"webBrowser.FindElementByClass("field Name") doesn't work"

It's because there can be multiple elements with the same class name. Hence it should be:
webBrowser.FindElementsByClass("field Name")

Note the s for plural elements: webBrowser.FindElement s ByClass("field Name")